# how to make content of NSString goes to next line based on \n on iphone

Tags: iphone

i have a **NSString s=@"hi\nhello\n\nwelcome to this world\ni m jhon"**

now **how to display this content in UIlabel** so that **\n allow 1 line gap** and **\n\n allows 2 line gap**

still i am getting same value

```
NSString *s=aDl.content;// aDl.content=hi\nhello\n\nwelcome to this world\ni m jhon





            labelb.text=s;// its same without line break  :(
```

kindly help me

Thanks

Comment: if i  pass value to NSString from other class and then label.text=string  then its not working , but if i define NSSring value with @""  and then pass then its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set label's height big enough to accommodate all lines in your string. Then set label's numberOfLines property to 0 - so label will draw its text in as much lines as required. New lines symbols (\n) will be handled by label automatically:

```
NSString *s=@"hi\nhello\n\nwelcome to this world\ni m jhon"
label.frame = ...//big enough height
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.text = s;
```

Comment: its still same plz check above